# How do I change the <p> text inside a class?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[Code I'm trying to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR1uQ.png)

I have tried the following code to change the p text without any success, I'm not sure how to call the p in order to change the text, how do I call this?

```css
p.min-pariticipants  { 

font-weight: bold;
color: red;
font-size: 30px;

<p> Test </p>

}
```

Comment: You're trying to change the text or style of the text? The <p> tag wouldn't go inside of the css style.

Comment: Changing the **text** using CSS???? This doesn't make sense!

Comment: CSS can't manipulate the content of HTML tags. You can only ADD content before or after the HTML content.

Comment: Is your CS loading before or after WordPress'? What's WordPress' specificity on that class?

Comment: I don't think the OP is trying to change the text content but rather change the styling. I could be wrong but I think they just phrased their question poorly

Comment: But they did add `<p> Test </p>` **inside** the css style, that's why I think this is quite literally what the OP is trying to do

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish; but writing HTML inside CSS is a no go. If you're trying to change the contents of the `p` tag and you don't have access to the actual HTML; then you can use a small line JavaScript to accomplish this.

```js
document.getElementById('test').innerText = "Change Me!"
```

```html
<p id="test">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

If you're looking to add additional content to the `p` tag, then you can use the CSS pseudo selectors `::after` or `::before`; this will put new content alongside the pre-existing one.

```css
#test::after {
  content:' After'
}
#test::before {
  content:'Before '
}
```

```html
<p id="test">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```